# Why Pandas gives AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'pct'?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to pass a user defined function `pct` to Pandas `agg` method, and it works if I only pass that function but it doesn't when I use the dictionary format for defining the functions. Does anyone know why?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]],
                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

pct = lambda x: len(x)/len(df)

df.groupby('A').agg(pct)
```

returns as expected

```
    B   C
A       
1   0.333333    0.333333
4   0.333333    0.333333
7   0.333333    0.333333
```

But

```
aggs = {'B':['pct']}
df.groupby('A').agg(aggs)
```

returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'pct'
```

Comment: Your function is `pct` not `'pct'`, which is a string which `.agg()` won't know how to associate with a function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is string `'pct'`, need variable `pct` - lambda function by removing `''`:

```
aggs = {'B':pct}
print(df.groupby('A').agg(aggs))

          B
A          
1  0.333333
4  0.333333
7  0.333333
```